# Python list index value is not returned properly

Tags: python

I have a string and Im trying to get the index of value "bad" and for some reason it throws me an error.

```
>>> s = "This dinner is not that bad!"
>>> l = s.split()
>>> bad_index_value = l.index('bad')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you have not `bad` in your list its `bad!`. if you want to find the index of `bad` you can strip the element with `'!'`:

```
>>> s = "This dinner is not that bad!"
>>> s.strip().split()
['This', 'dinner', 'is', 'not', 'that', 'bad!']
>>> 
>>> l=s.strip('!').split()
>>> l.index('bad')
5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = "This dinner is not that bad !"
>>> l = s.split()
>>> bad_index_value = l.index('bad') # will give you the index.
```

Technically `bad` is not present in your input `This dinner is not that bad!`, its `bad!`

Comment: But this is not the op's input.

Comment: Yes, i am telling him why his case failed and which one will pass so that he can know issue by himself. I gave example for his expected o/p.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "This dinner is not that bad!"
>>> re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',s).split().index('bad')
5
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split()` instead of `string.split()`. The use of regular expressions allows specifying both the `!` and whitespace (`\s`) as a delimiter:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "This dinner is not that bad!"
>>> l = re.split("[!\s]", s)
>>> bad_index_value = l.index('bad')
>>> bad_index_value
5
```

Note that `l` now contains a trailing empty string (because one of the delimiters is at the end of the string):

```
>>> l
['This', 'dinner', 'is', 'not', 'that', 'bad', '']
```

If necessary, you can use a list comprehension to remove it:

```
>>> l= [x for x in re.split("[!\s]", s) if x]
>>> l
['This', 'dinner', 'is', 'not', 'that', 'bad']
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to split the string into a list just run

```
>>> s = "This dinner is not that bad!"
>>> s.find("bad")
24  # s[24] = 'b'
```